# Bringing Partial Data Using Jquery Ajax

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I'm new to Jquery. I have a textbox on an aspx page. When 2 letters typed the textbox brings the Turkey Postcodes from sql server database using jquery ajax. But if there are more than 900 records to be returned from the sql server, jquery gives an "internal server error". I think it needs more time to bring the data to the textbox, but jquery doesn't allow that and give an internal error. Now I wish to bring the partial data on first request. For example; if the user writes 34 in the textbox, ajax will not bring all the data which starts with 34. It will bring the first 100 results. And then when the user slides the scrollbar to the end of the records, new records will be queried and be shown to the user. Just like the same as facebook posts.Is it possible? If it is, I'd be glad if you share us a sample code.
Here is my codes..

Javascript

```
$(function() {
$(".tb").autocomplete
        ({
             source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "WebService_GetData.asmx/GetCmbPostaKod",
                    dataType: "json",
                    //data: "{ 'filterKey': '" + request.term + "','select1': '" + $('#cmbLogisticType').val() + "' }",
                    data: JSON.stringify({filterKey: request.term, lojtype:$('#cmbLogisticType').val(), ulke:$asp('ulke').val()}),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataFilter: function(data) { return data; },
                    success: function(data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function(item) {
                        return { value: item.PostaKodu, label: item.SemtAdi + ' / ' + item.IlceAdi + ' / ' + item.IlAdi + ' - ' + item.PostaKodu }
                        }))
                    },
                    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(errorThrown);
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 2,
            multiple: true,
            matchContains: true,
            formatItem: formatItem,
            formatResult: formatResult
        });
    });
```

Code Behind aspx.cs

```
    [WebMethod]
    public List<PostaKod> GetCmbPostaKod(string filterKey, string lojtype, string ulke)
    {

        string stmt;
        DataTable dt;
        //myToolKit.AddValueToCombo(cmbVergiDairesi, "0", "Seçiniz");
        //myToolKit.AddValueToCombo(cmbSatisElemani, "0", "Seçiniz");
        FunctionsToolkit.InjectionKontrolEt(ref filterKey);
        mySqlKit.DoConnect();
        /*
        stmt = string.Format(@"SELECT ILADI, ILCEADI, SEMTADI, POSTAKODU, ULKEKODU FROM TBLPOSTAKODLARI (NOLOCK)
                               WHERE POSTAKODU LIKE '{0}%' AND ULKEKODU='{1}' ORDER BY POSTAKODU", filterKey, (lojtype=="3")?ulke:lojtype);
        */
        stmt = string.Format(@"EXEC sp_get_postakodu '{0}','{1}'",filterKey,(lojtype=="3")?ulke:lojtype);
        dt = mySqlKit.DoDTstr(stmt);
        mySqlKit.DoDisconnect();
        return mySqlKit.ComboDList(dt);
    }
```

Page aspx

```
    <div id="panel1">
       Nakliye Tipini Seçiniz* :
       <select name="LogisticType" id="cmbLogisticType" onchange="toggle(this.value)">
           <option value="1" selected="selected"> Seçiniz </option>
           <option value="90"> Şehiriçi </option>
           <option value="90"> Şehirlerarası </option>
           <option value="3"> Uluslararası </option>
        </select>
        <!--
       <asp:DropDownList ID="cmbPostaKodu" name="cmbPostaKodu" runat="server" class="combo">
       </asp:DropDownList>
       <select ID="cmbIl" name="cmbIl" runat="server" onchange="ilceGetir(this.options[this.options.selectedIndex].value)" class="combo"></select>
       <select ID="cmbIlce" name="cmbIlce" runat="server" class="combo"></select>-->
    </div>
    <div class="slidingDiv">
        <div class="slidingDiv2">
              Hareket Noktası (Ülke):
                <div class="ui-widget">
                    <div class="text1">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="ulke" class="tb" runat="server" onfocus="this.value = ( this.value == this.defaultValue ) ? '' : this.value;return true;">Ülke Seçiniz</asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>

                 Varış Noktası (Ülke):
                <div class="ui-widget">
                    <div class="text1">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="ulke2" class="tb" runat="server" onfocus="this.value = ( this.value == this.defaultValue ) ? '' : this.value;return true;">Ülke Seçiniz</asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        Hareket Noktası (Posta Kodu):
        <div class="ui-widget">
            <div class="text1">
                <asp:TextBox ID="city" class="tb" runat="server" onfocus="this.value = ( this.value == this.defaultValue ) ? '' : this.value;return true;">Posta Kodu Giriniz</asp:TextBox>
            </div>
        </div>
        Varış Noktası (Posta Kodu): 
          <div class="ui-widget">

            <div class="text1">  
                <asp:TextBox ID="city2" class="tb" runat="server" onfocus="this.value = ( this.value == this.defaultValue ) ? '' : this.value;return true;">Posta Kodu Giriniz</asp:TextBox>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for you would be to limit your server-side query result set using `TOP n` (assuming you are using SQL Server). Make `n` a number that makes sense to you. No user is going to browse for 900 options. Make it, say, 20.

If the user want more options, more typing will be required.

Comment: Thank you by It's not a good solution for me. Users may be able to see the whole data if they scroll down the postcodes. Data should come in pieces. I can't limit by using top n.